# How to print <br> as text and not a line break

Tags: php, html

I have a php script that opens a text file. Within this text file has several tags such as `<br/>` in it.

What I want is the entire 30,000 line text file to print everything as text, including tags.

So no tags are enabled, and they're displayed as text instead.

Right now my code looks like:

```
<?php
$myfilename = "newer.txt";
if(file_exists($myfilename)){
  echo html_entity_decode(file_get_contents($myfilename));
}
?>
```

And nothing changes. A lot of the tags such as `<button>, <br>, and <image>` just take over the entire page.

I'm still looking for a simple way to stop tags, and view them as text.

Comment: There is a deprecated <xmp></xmp> tag, that displays the html code between as text, but using the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)() function is a safer bet.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($myfilename));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
&lt;br&gt;
```

In HTML, 
`&gt;` means >
`&lt;` means <

So, replace < with `&lt;`;
And > with `&gt;`

Comment: That's nothing to do with PHP, that's HTML.

Comment: @RenatoA. Please read the ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: Oopps, stack overflow changed the answer. &lt; is the char code for <, and &gt; is the char code for >

Comment: @FinnShadow I fixed your formatting. You can read more about how to format your posts here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @RenatoA. `<p>` and `<br>` have both existed in every version of HTML (since 1.0!), and have always had distinct meanings. They are not replacements for one another.

Answer (score 0):

use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($myfilename));
```